# Обособление оборота с предлогом «вне зависимости от» при отсутствии уточняющего значения

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, обстоятельственный-оборот, присоединительная-конструкция

**ВСТУПЛЕНИЕ**

Этот предложный оборот не раз обсуждался на форуме, но там речь шла о его **пояснительном или уточняющем** значении. А это принципиальный вопрос, так как  при отсутствии уточнения решение будет выглядеть  иначе.  В этом случае действует  **[правило Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114)** о факультативном обособлении обстоятельств, выраженных существительными с предлогами.

Итак, мы можем **не обособлять** оборот, а также можем его **обособить**, причем **не только запятой, но и тире**.

**Какое решение** вы примете в приведенных предложениях и почему?  Приведены шесть примеров, **по два примера** на каждый вариант.

Можно сначала дать **одни ответы**, а объяснение по дополнительной просьбе. Но можно дать короткое объяснение **сразу** (какой именно фактор определил ваш выбор).

**ПРИМЕРЫ**

(1) Уже приведенных сведений вполне достаточно, чтобы утверждать, что лирическое и сатирическое начало в произведениях Довлатова сосуществуют (?) **вне зависимости от сюжетной основы.**

(2)  **Вне зависимости от времени суток** (?) вам откроют монастырские святыни для поклонения…

(3) Все документальное, попадая на сцену, становится условным (?) **вне зависимости от** присутствия в спектакле танцев, песен и анимации.

(4) Каждый фрагмент (?) **вне зависимости от своего размера** (?) расположен на отдельной странице, что дает читателю возможность делать небольшую паузу перед каждым новым стихотворением.

(5) Я думаю, что книга (как и картина) излучает определенную энергию, излучает ее спонтанно и постоянно (?) **вне зависимости от того**, обращаются к данной книге или нет.

(6) Приоритетными будут малозатратные информационные проекты, чтобы можно было привлечь к реализации программы как можно больше СМИ (?) **вне зависимости от их форм собственности.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. *Уже приведенных сведений вполне достаточно, чтобы утверждать, что лирическое и сатирическое начало в произведениях Довлатова / сосуществуют **вне зависимости от сюжетной основы***.

Выбор однозначен: без оборота предложение выглядит незаконченным. Произносительная пауза делается перед сказуемым, и ударение переходит на оборот – "ядро" высказывания.

2. ***Вне зависимости от времени суток,** вам откроют монастырские святыни для поклонения…*

Этот пример кажется "самым факультативным". Почему бы не поставить запятую просто из-за наличия паузы? Может, имеет значение начальная позиция оборота? Если его переставить, то обособления не будет: *Вам откроют монастырские святыни для поклонения **вне зависимости от времени суток***.

3. *Все документальное, попадая на сцену, становится условным **– вне зависимости от присутствия в спектакле танцев, песен и анимации***.

Здесь оборот носит присоединительный характер. Тире, как более сильный графический и интонационный знак, лучше подходит, чем запятая (тем более что первая часть и так осложнена деепричастным оборотом).
Но в этом предложении может и не быть обособления, если в контексте уже была речь об *условности, танцах, песнях и анимации*. Тогда не будет паузы перед оборотом.

4. *Каждый фрагмент, **вне зависимости от своего размера,** расположен на отдельной странице, что дает читателю возможность делать небольшую паузу перед каждым новым стихотворением.*

Оборот расположен между подлежащим и сказуемым, имеет второстепенное значение, читается со вставочной интонацией.

5. *Я думаю, что книга (как и картина) излучает определенную энергию, излучает ее спонтанно и постоянно **– вне зависимости от того, обращаются к данной книге или нет***.

Оборот – присоединение.

6. *Приоритетными будут малозатратные информационные проекты, чтобы можно было привлечь к реализации программы как можно больше СМИ **вне зависимости от их форм собственности***.

В этом случае выбор будет зависеть от контекста и авторской расстановки акцентов.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ, я его принимаю, решения верные. Мне не хватает обобщения темы. Два примера без обособления просчитываются быстро, а что потом?  Управление ослабляется на каком этапе?  И на каком этапе связь становится присоединительной (скобки можно поставить). Как влияет распространенность первой и второй части? Какая распространенность более значима? Помогите по возможности понять что-нибудь из сказанного. Мне эти вопросы нужны для анализа другого предложения)

Comment: Ух!.. Я не теоретик, не обобщатель. Всё на всё влияет, и как ни банально, смысл рулит. Спасибо, Sharon!

Comment: Спасибо еще раз!